# OAuth redirect uri missing '?code=' parameter

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, nestjs, passport.js, instagram

When trying to implement OAuth2 authorization with Instagram API, I'm having trouble with the redirect URL. After the user grants permission in the Instagram authorization modal, I'm redirected to a URL that looks like this:

`https://localhost:3333/api/provider/instagram/redirect<_accesToken>`

the URL is missing the code parameter, normaly it should look like this :

`https://localhost:3333/api/provider/instagram/redirect?code=<_accesToken>`

It worked perfectly but when I added the http service in my strategy to call the Instagram API and convert a short time access token to a long time access token, the strategy stopped working and it started to return wierd redirect URIs.

I removed all added code in the strategy but it wont work again.

I'm unable to figure out what is causing this issue and would appreciate any help in resolving it.

I'm using NestJS and the passport-instagram-basic-api strategy.